# Best zoom to points in google maps api v2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

How can I best zoom to group of points in google maps api v2? In api v3 I would use bounds object to store the points and then zoom to these bounds using `fitBounds()` function, but in v2 I really don't know.

I found some advice here, but the solution of writing custom function seems quite clumsy...
http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/996f83e075e51fdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this mini tutorial, it sounds like what you want:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic14.htm

```
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
for (... each point ...) {
    bounds.extend(latlng); 
}
map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map14.htm